# DIV container covering full height

Tags: css, html

I would like the line between the sidebar and the main content to cover the full height here: 
http://web182.theta.ibone.ch/vbl/fileadmin/templates/

I did set the height of the div container and all parent containers to 100%, but still the line is not covering the full height? Who can help?

CSS files are here:

http://web182.theta.ibone.ch/vbl/fileadmin/templates/css/base.css
http://web182.theta.ibone.ch/vbl/fileadmin/templates/css/screen/screen-PAGE-layout.css

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, HTML and CSS is trouble when dealing with height alignment. Usually you have to resort to other methods.

In your case, I'd put that "line" on the content element (the element with the main page content) instead of the block on the right - that way it always covers the height of the body.